# Word for "software with a large size"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In Portuguese, we use "software pesado", which translates to "heavy software", but it doesn't sound right.

How can I say: "this software has a large size"? When its size is over many gigabytes for example.

Is there an adjective for this in English? What are some common ways of describing software size?

Comment: I was a programmer for several decades and I don't recall any idiomatic expression for this.  "Too big" is about as good as it got.  (Well, that and some profanities.)

Comment: Do you mean this in the sense that the Spanish do when then speak of *software inflado*  or *software hinchado* (which should be nearly the same in Portuguese: *inflado* or *inchado*)? That is, puffed up too big like a balloon that's going to explode or an elephant that's grown too big to skip lightly down the road like a modern-day dinosaur, a ponderous behemoth. I'm trying to understand if you mean something else other than [software bloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bloat) here.

Comment: What's wrong with "large"?

Comment: ***Monolith***?

Comment: "heavy software" or "huge software" are much better choices than what others are suggesting in answers and comments. So, keep calling it "software pesado", it is the best so far.

Comment: Are you talking about software with a large [_application footprint_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_footprint)?

Comment: Please distinguish whether you're talking about _storage space_ vs. _resources needed to run_ (e.g., memory) and whether you're talking about just _large_ or you specifically mean _inefficient or wasteful_.

Comment: Heavy software sounds perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: Maybe *monster* software? Godzilla comes to mind.

Comment: Clarify if referring to client apps or server side software.

Comment: Another possibility is *beast*.

Comment: “[Enterprisey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enterprisey)” has long been my favoured term for software that is unnecessarily large.

Comment: Major application?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Monolith is an architectural term, isn't it?

Comment: @kutschkem, Might be. I wasn't sure about it that's why it's a 'comment'.

Comment: What about *bulky*? If it's also cumbersome or laggy, maybe *unwieldy* is a good alternative.

Comment: Would "Behemoth" fit this case ?

Comment: I suggest 'Microsoftian'.

Comment: The same idiom in Swedish...

Comment: I usually use term "**complex**" - complex IS (information system), complex CAE system (Computer Aided Engineering), etc. Definitely not bloatware. Software can have tons of useful features, but it doesn't make it *bloatware*, even though some users won't be able to use some. What IMHO makes bloatware is *unnecessary* use of software libraries, libraries to update libraries, libraries to resolve issues between libraries, frameworks and framework layers, etc.

Comment: We have been using **Bloatware** for at least 30 years. The threshold has grown dramatically along with Parkinson's law. I remember Paul Lyons referring to the next version of their flagship extended DOS software as bloatware, because the executable file was several megabytes. *Yes it's **BIIIG**! but at least it's SLOWWW!*. BtW the company was **not** Microsoft :)

Comment: Hi. Native Portuguese speaker here (and I can't answer due to lack of reputation here, just comment). Although the OP mentions 'large _size_', the idiomatic expression in Portuguese is _both_ pejorative and more abstract/subjective than merely indicating that the software takes several GBytes of disk/memory space. It means _mostly_ that a specific piece of software 'consumes a lot of resources' and _implicitly_ also means that it's very slow (compared to the _user's expectations_), which obviously depends on the kind of machine that it's running on.

Comment: Personally, I'd use *bloated* in this context, although, IMHO, 'bloated' usually implies bad software design (in the sense that, if written correctly, that particular piece of software _could_ be 'un-bloated'). _Pesado_ doesn't have that implication: the software _may_ be _correctly_ written, according to all sorts of best practices, but, due to its specific peculiarities and the context it runs under, it might _always_ be _pesado_.

Comment: A few examples that come to mind: opening an AutoCAD drawing with hundreds of layers and dozens of thousands of objects per layer on an underpowered machine, or compiling a very complex application with hundreds of thousands of lines of code with an optimising compiler... in both scenarios, the software will be '_pesado_' from the perspective of the _user_, although in different circumstances (lighter drawing being loaded; small application with few files being compiled), the _same_ application _might_ not be a 'resource hog'.

Comment: Since the 1990's I use to call such bloated-up, memory-hungry, heavily embellished however bug-laden, horrible software as "Microsoftical"... but that's just me, as far as I know. Oh, and I know pretty well what you mean, since I'm a native speaker of Portuguese! ~~~ Em português, eu os chamo de "Microsóftico", com a pronúncia do primeiro "i" como no inglês: /ai/.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use **bloated** as a somewhat loaded term which is also a bit ambiguous: it may indicate software which takes up a lot of disk space, is memory-hungry, and/or works slowly. It may also suggest there are too many features or that they are cumbersome to use.

More technical (and also more specific) terms include: software with a **big disk (or memory etc.) footprint** and **resource-intensive** software. On a more generic note, you can say the software is **demanding** (though without any context, it may not be clear if it's demanding of the computing resources or of the user).

Comment: "Bloated" is not just a loaded term, it explicitly means software that is *too big*. Something that is big because it does a lot of necessary things is not "bloated".

Comment: @DJClayworth but one person's necessary things are another's bloat and very few users use everything, thus all broadly-featured software could be regarded as bloated for most users

Comment: @ChrisH There's lots of logical arguments around that, but whatever the case "bloated" is not just a synonym for large.

Comment: @DJClayworth on a technical basis I agree completely.  For most popular software my opinion is that they may as well be synonymous, but that's off-topic, as my opinions often are

Comment: Bloatware means the software has lots of unnecessary things. A game with 200GB of level assets wouldn't be considered bloatware if they're all an integral part of the game's experience.

Comment: @curiousdannii A game with 200GB of assets using poorly compressed or uncompressed images, and audio sampled at 192 KHz, could be accused of bloat.

Comment: @ChrisH: Something being subjective doesn't make it linguistically incorrect. If I call something bloatware (or bloated software), **I** deem it to have an unreasonable amount of unnecessary features. Language polices the legibility of a sentence, it does not fact-check if that sentence matches real life. Your suggestion is akin to stating that "tasty" is not the right word to use to convey you like a meal, because some people might not like that same meal.

Comment: @Flater I'm not sure which suggestion you're referring to, as I didn't intend to make a suggestion. I agree with your first sentence, but I seem to come to a different conclusion - synonyms are context-dependent and it may or may not be appropriate to insert your judgement.  I'd say exchanging  "large" and  "bloated" is rather like describing a person as "100kg" or "fat" (if tall enough, one doesn't even imply the other).  I've even come across small but bloated software - in fact I've produced it, when Visual Basic used to package huge runtimes with tiny utilities

Comment: demanding seems fairly natural. resource-intensive as well. thank you very much for your contribution, I appreciate it. I must thank as well people who suggested "bulky" and the guy who told us that it's better to use program/file/application instead of software. I already use "bloated" with my friends and fellow students but that's only when I'm making fun of a program for being unnecessarily big. The purpose of the question was to address all huge apps, like video editors, and that kind of demanding software.

Answer (score 58):

In a neutral pair of phrases, you could call a piece of software **lightweight** at one end of the scale and **resource intensive** at the other end.

From the Reddit thread ["Least resource intensive web browsers"](https://www.reddit.com/r/browsers/comments/g1q8tq/least_resource_intensive_web_browsers/):

> What would be the least hardware intensive web browsers these days? I am currently running Firefox 75.0 (64-bit) which is great in terms of functionality however it is utilizing nearly 1.1 GB of memory which is around 80% of the total memory available on my laptop. I have only three tabs opened one of the being reddit and a few active extensions …
>
> - **comodo icedragon** is by far the best lightweight browser i’ve ever used on my intel atom processor windows tablet. it has full firefox addon compatibility, themes, syncing (even the open tabs), and built-in adblocker if you don’t want resource intensive addons. it’s responsive and amazingly easy on the ram. i have more than 13 tabs open and active at the same time right now with ublock origin, nano defender and decentraleyes running and it’s taking up around 700mb of ram, which is what chrome uses for 3 tabs.

*Resource* can be replaced by the specific resource. In the context of this question, it would be *disk intensive*.

---

If it's meant in a pejorative sense (meaning that the software's size has made it take up too many resources for too little return), a common expression is **bloatware**:

From [Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/4237/bloatware):

> Bloatware is software that has unnecessary features that use large amounts of memory and RAM. Software comes to be known as bloatware when it becomes so unwieldy that its functionality is drowned out by its useless features. This is also known as software bloat …
>
> Bloatware usually occurs as a result of feature creep. Because software is traditionally redesigned on a yearly basis, many developers feel the need to add additional functionality in order to entice users into upgrading the existing software. Unfortunately, the added features increase the size of the program and the system requirements needed to run it smoothly, eventually forcing the user to upgrade in order to run the latest software.

---

Comment: *Bloatware* is what I would say (though it's usually used for preinstalled software).

Comment: You start with lightweight, and the OP's original word is "heavy". Is there a reason you skipped _heavyweight_?

Comment: @OwenReynolds I have never heard *heavyweight* used in relation to software before. To me, that seems quite out of place.

Comment: Heavyweight feels less natural to me as well, but it's an obvious option and a search for "heavyweight process" shows it's common enough for "resource intensive".

Comment: As an AmE developer, _disk-intensive_ is unfamiliar to me, and I'd interpret it as software that does a lot of disk reads/writes, not software that takes a lot of disk space.

Comment: I'd disagree somewhat.  Bloatware isn't primarily due to "feature creep", but comes from unskilled developers who don't really know how to write compact & efficient programs.  Likewise, programs can be fairly small but still bloated, or really big yet efficient because they need to be that big to do their job.

Comment: As a 15 experienced year computer tech and an 8 year experienced software dev, I consider "bloatware" to be the extra software on a new PC that was put on there by the manufacturer by paid advertisers of their software. I've never heard it used to reference feature creep or unnecessary functionality. https://www.computerworld.com/article/2966113/bloatware-what-it-is-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it.html

Comment: @OwenReynolds I'd use *heavy-weight program/application" as well. Intuitive and immediately understandable.

Comment: I've been programming for 39 years now. I first heard terms like "software bloat" and "bloatware" at least a quarter century ago. It did not necessarily refer to anything pre-installed.

Comment: Here is a parody song from 1997 sung to the tune of Jingle Bells: http://humour.davintech.ca/microsoft-bloatware.phtml  *"Oh! Microsoft, Microsoft,
Bloatware all the way!
I've sat here installing Word
Since breakfast yesterday!"*. The song is clearly not about pre-installed software. Large quantities of preinstalled software weren't that common, then; certainly not before the internet age (because the crapware needs a  network to talk to to hook you into walled garden services).  I had an audio recording of this song on my HD around that time, possibly by the original author.

Comment: @Kaz sometimes software is "half pre-installed", meaning that at first start up it must continue installing before being used. Windows on pre-built computers and, IIRC, Office is an example of that. And I'm not old enough, but a pre-installed trial version of Office sounds pretty plausible to me even at that time.

Comment: @braco Nope at that time most computers did not have connection to a network. You installed from disks and no extra trial software. Blotware was often used for MS software as some people said it could be programmed better with much less code - or look at emacs for earlier bloatware complaints

Answer (score 36):

**Bloatware** is a term for a piece of software that is (in the opinion of the speaker) *too* large.  It used to be used a lot for programs like Microsoft Word that showed the user far more features than he would likely ever use, before they learned to hide those options behind user-friendly toolbars.

**Resource hog** or **memory hog** might be used for a program which consumes a large part of the system's available resources, especially if this impacts other programs running on the machine.  (The word "hog", which literally means "pig", is often used in English to mean something like "glutton".)

Or maybe you mean **enterprise software**?  That term refers to large systems that run on servers and are used by several people throughout an organization; for example an HR system, or a manufacturing planning system.  These are indeed very large software systems.  If you're talking about an older enterprise system, one that may be written in an old language that is difficult to maintain, but which the organization can't do without, we call that a **legacy system**.  Legacy systems are often **monolithic** (i.e., all one big piece) which makes them hard to modify.

Comment: "Monolithic" is the closest I could come up with too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_application  "described enormous main frame applications with no usable modularity"

Comment: Trying to maintain a monolithic legacy system is my day job.  If it were modular, it'd be easy to pick it apart and re-write one section at a time, but it's not.

Comment: @workerjoe "Monolithic" only describes the internal design of the software

Comment: Although a good suggestion, "bloatware" had a specific connotation when it was coined as to the reason for a "bloated" size. As someone active in software, i recall the word emerging in the late 1990s as polemical against the use of object oriented libraries and the software re-use ideas that people were heavily exploiting at the time. If not polemical, then the word had at least a connotation of raising the need to address the massive increase in size these software reuse ideas led to: the benefits (huge increase in the complexity developers could handle) on the whole outweighed the ...

Comment: ... disadvantages: the word was often used anticipating the "next generation" of software reuse ideas beyond OO where this problem would be solved. Memory availability and CPU power was still increasing exponentially with time in accordance with the then valid Moore's law, so the problem was never fully addressed. But, as a result of software use measures, many programs use only a small fraction of their available code.

Comment: Linux is a monolithic kernel, which seems to have some objective advantages. Monolithic != bloated != hard to maintain.

Comment: @EricDuminil I don't know much about kernel programming, but "monolithic" in something like an enterprise application (think ERP system) means to me that it can't be broken down into units and subsystems, and therefore it's very difficult to write unit tests and subsystem tests.  In that kind of software if it's not testable I don't consider it easy to maintain.

Comment: @workerjoe Monolithic does not mean badly designed (e.g. spaghetti code) either! https://m.signalvnoise.com/the-majestic-monolith/

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I didn't say it did.  Monolithic means that it's basically all one big chunk, not easily divisible into subsections.

Answer (score 16):

Jason Bassford suggested *lightweight* for one end of the scale; for the other end, I'd suggest the obvious opposite: **heavyweight**.

That can carry connotations of size (installation, codebase, and/or UI/API), the complexity of what it does, the resources it uses (CPU, memory, storage, and/or servers), cost, level of robustness/redundancy, or even prestige/reputation.

Or you could simply describe a piece of software as **big**.

That's more specifically about aspects that can be measured, most usually the size of its installation.

---

And in response to some of the other answers and comments: in standard English ‘software’ is a *mass noun* (like ‘air’ or ‘bread’): you can talk about *some* software, or *a piece of* software, but you can't refer to ‘*a* software’ (nor to ‘softwares’).  (Even though it might be more convenient to do so!)

Comment: I'd understand "heavyweight" as referring to marketshare or mindshare, not size.

Answer (score 8):

Disk-hungry; storage-hungry; is bulky; has a large disk-footprint / storage-footprint; has high storage requirements; gobbles up/eats up/requires a lot of storage space

I presume you're referring to its storage requirements, not its main memory usage.

Comment: I think just 'large footprint' is enough. It implies memory, disk and CPU usage will be high.

Comment: @displayName I agree, as a general term, but the OP specifically asked for a term for software that is large in SIZE, not necessarily in CPU usage - and initially for an adjective, rather than a noun-phrase.  The alternatives I put forward were the suggestions of a computer programmer, who took it that the OP was talking of storage-requirements rather than resource-use at runtime because the software was described as being "over many gigabytes", which might be considered extraordinarily memory-demanding for a running program even in 2020.

Answer (score 8):

> In Portuguese, we use "software pesado", which translates to "heavy software", but it doesn't sound right.

No, it doesn't. The problem is that English does not use "software" in that context - it would use "program" or "file" or "application".

> How can I say: "this software has a large size"?

"This program/file/application takes up a lot of disk-space."

> Another pain is that, because the program takes up a lot of disk space, battles in progress must be saved to another disk. ("MacWorld 8708 August 1987)

"This program/file/application is huge."

> @ADyson I already thought on that, but this application is huge and I need to migrate the architecture step by step. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804665/cannot-access-to-physical-html-file

Comment: I also like the answers that reference "footprint" and "hungry" -- they are useful and common.

Answer (score 4):

"Big" is a simple adjective used to describe the size and resource requirements of software, although "big" is not often used with the word "software" itself.

A "big program" would be understood by many English native speakers who work with computers to mean software that has a large file size, large footprint on disk, and probably large memory requirements. Photoshop is a big program compared to FileZilla, for example.

"A big piece of software" is another expression that would be understood as software with many large files, requiring a large amount of disk space, and likely computer resources as well.

To directly answer the question, I don't believe there is a simple, well-understood  English idiom for "software that takes a huge amount of disk space."

Answer (score 4):

There is no English equivalent, or at least it’s gone out of use as everybody has terabyte hard drives these days and plenty of RAM.

However at one time you might have got your feet muddy and said:

> The software has a large [footprint](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/footprin.htm)

Which in plain English means:

> The software takes up a lot of disc space

or

> The software uses a lot of memory

Of course if you must bring on the heavies, you could have recoded that as:

> The software is [heavy on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heavy%20on) disc space

But don’t let it weigh on your mind.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a native speaker of American English, and a professional programmer for over 10 years, and I do commonly hear and use "**heavy**" as a standard idiomatic descriptor for resource-intensive software. In fact, it was what I was going to suggest, based just on the question title, even before reading the question.

> Example: "Should we install that new npm package?"
> "I don't know, it's kind of **heavy**, given what we're going to use it for."

The only caveat is that you'd more likely say "X is heavy" rather than "X is a piece of 'heavy software.'"

Answer (score 0):

When describing well-crafted software that needs to be large and/or intricate to do its job, I tend to use terms that convey size and weight, volume and mass, density, power.

As an example, I've called some applications "bulldozers": large powerful machines that get the job done.  Like a good DBMS.

At the other end of the scale are "hummingbirds": tiny swift utilities that are done and gone before you notice them.  Like much of the Linux command-line.

Of course, these metaphorical descriptions are in no way "industry standard" simply because English has yet to evolve standard terminology for software characteristics that isn't either cumbersome to say or pejorative.

Comment: Hello, Bobc, welcome to EL&U! Can you add a pointer to a similar usage or definition of these metaphors, or are they your own inventions (answers are [better received](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) here if they are about language in use)? Cheers!

Comment: [***All*** computer terminology is metaphoric](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf). How could it be anything else? It could hardly be traditional -- there were no computers until 1950 or so, hence no traditions or traditional English terms.

Comment: Many (all?) fields are highly metaphoric in their infancy, then evolve their own concise internal terminology which may eventually leak into public discourse.  Psychology may be an ideal example, genetics another.

CS/software would appear to not yet follow that pattern.  Will it ever?

Answer (score 0):

When referring to client side software, the usual phrase is a **large *installation***.

We usually refer to the size of the installation on the client side, rather than say the total database size or server code size on the server.

If you are trying to differentiate a full native client vs a web client for an app, then the usual phrases are **fat client** vs **thin client**

For server side software there is no phrase. It is automatically assumed that the server app is heavy in all terms. If that's not the case, then it's described as *lightweight*

Answer (score 0):

Being a professional software engineer, I'd use the term **large-scale software** or even **ultra-large-scale systems** for really large systems.

Answer (score 0):

[Big Ball of Mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/)

A big ball of mud is something that has become quite unmanageable but it's still 'kind of' working so no one wants to rewrite the whole thing so you keep adding things on top.

This is especially true of network related services.

A slightly sexier name for the network based variety it is '[Microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices)' which is like a Big Ball of Mud managed slightly better.

Comment: I think "Big Ball of Mud" pertains to spaghetti, incomprehensible, unmaintainable, *source codes* — rather than software in compiled, packaged, and/or executable forms.

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of perspective. From the users' perspective they may just know the memory requirements. I'm just putting this here because it is a known term.

Answer (score 0):

Several phrases come to mind:

*Bloatware* is a common term. I've also come across *fatware*. Other terms in roughly the same area are *spaghetti code* and *junkware*. Or code packed with *boiler-plate code* - that is code that's just been pressed into service without much thought. It's the software equivalent of copy and paste ...

Answer (score 0):

Is the OP looking for a *pejorative* term (critical of the software), or just a descriptive term?

- **Monolithic** simply means that it's all in one piece; not broken up into separate modules or programs. Depending on the application, being monolithic may be justified, and not used as a pejorative term in that case.
- **Bloatware** is a subjective, pejorative term. The software includes too many features that are (subjectively) unnecessary, or is written inefficiently (taking up too much space on disk or in memory). Software that "has everything *including* the kitchen sink", but you'll never use 90% of the features, falls into the bloatware category.
- **disk/memory/CPU hog** uses a great deal of some resource, and in this sense ("hog") it's pejorative. Whether or not this is warranted depends on whether the large usage is justified by the functionality of the software, or whether it was simply poorly written.

If you're looking to criticize the size (footprint) of certain software by using a pejorative term, *bloatware* or *-- hog* may be appropriate. If you're looking simply to state that it's *large*, those terms are inappropriate. And *monolithic* is certainly a specific term pertaining to the architecture, and not the size.

Answer (score -1):

We don't use 'software' in that sense. It is a collective noun which includes source code, executables, etc. We don't say, "A room-sized mainframe is a big hardware", or anything similar.

See this recent [news item](https://www.theregister.com/2020/08/18/paragon_tries_to_contribute_ntfs) for an example of how others may tackle it.

Some examples:

> The source code is over a gigabyte.
>
> The source code is over 20,000 lines.
>
> The deliverable fills two DVDs.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you're trying to utilise the word **software** which is kind of too broad. You can say 'big computer program', which is straight enough. Or, at least, diskspace-demanding program.

Answer (score -2):

***Enterprise* software** is often used to indicate that a given application is non-trivial.

Comment: The term "enterprise software" typically refers to high quality and business-class level of support rather than size. I'm sure there was plenty of "enterprise software" back in the 1980s and early 1990s that fit inside a few megabytes, for example.

Comment: @user1258361 "A few megabytes" were elephantine in the 1980s, though. Welcome to EL&U, RikRak! Please do give some time to take the [tour] if you haven't. Could you give a pointer to an example where this term is used or defined? Cheers!